# VirtualBox: Failed to create the host only network interface

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I am attempting to create a host-only network interface and the following occurs:

[image]

This is on VBox 4.3.30 on Yosemite

Comment: Any reason why you are not going to 5.0.10? It might be just fixed in the in-between versions.

Comment: I did upgrade to latest (5.x) and the error is not showing up there.